# Total positive charge in the Universe

Tags: universe, charge, protons

In their last homework, some of my students miscalculated a charge to be $10^{20}$ C over a squared meter and I was wondering if there was as much positive charges in the entire Universe. It would do the trick if I could simply estimate the total number of protons (including those in nucleus) in the entire Universe but how to do so in a simple way ?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the Eddington number, see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_number. Maybe this is be a good basis to answer your question.

Comment: Just in case anyone is misled, it might be worth re-emphasizing that Eddington's argument for the number is probably only good for its comedy value.  The following [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content) which is given on that wiki page is the one to follow for a more reasonable justification of the value.

Comment: The total charge of the universe is actually not a well-defined quantity. There is a discussion of this on p. 457 of Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler for the case of a spatially closed universe. It holds more trivially in the case of a spatially infinite universe, since there's no particular reason for the result to be finite. If you meant the observable universe, then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content