# Are objects generally neutral or charged?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, conservation-laws, charge

Basically the questions relates to what is taught about electroneutrality and has 2 parts:

- Is the overall charge in the universe zero?
- Are objects the world generally neutral or slightly charged, constantly passing a little bit of charge from one to the other on contact?

Comment: The two questions should be separated IMHO. I.e. take one out of here and post it as a new question

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59655/  but not a duplicate, as it discusses the total positive charge (cf. net charge) in universe.

Comment: Hi @innisfree I think the two questions are related. If the first answer is "not zero" then the second question answers itself. I'm wondering if we're all walking around more or less charged, and if every object will have some charge difference with respect to others or not. The question came from a neuromodulation problem I have, but I realised it's very general.

Comment: If the first answer is not zero, what is the answer to the second that follows immediately?

Comment: Well I suppose that if the overall charge is not zero, it means that at least 1 object in the universe is charged. As usually anomalies like this don't happen in physics I would conclude that if the charge is non-zero, the total charge would be large and distributed and all objects would have more protons than electrons for example. But yeah I guess that's a lot of "ifs" and assumptions on my part.

Comment: @innisfree I kind of always assumed the total charge to be zero, but wanted this confirmed... My main question about the charge of objects is more practical. Static electricity for example causes some objects to be charged, I'm wondering if this is the general case, or if most objects are neutral and a net charge is rare and due to "extreme circumstances".

Answer (score 1):

The answer involves the current model of the universe. The current model, the [Big Bang model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), assumes that everything is charge neutral from the beginning of he appearance of the universe almost 14 billion years ago.

The model incorporates the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics and uses it to project the generation of the currently observed universe.

In this model there are conservation laws, some of which are strict, and conservation of  charge is one of them. This at atomic level means that there should be as many electrons as protons in the universe, to keep it neutral. Neutrality exists in the everyday level, since it is the statistically most probable state: due to the attraction of positive to negative charges extra energy must be supplied to separate them and keep them separate.

> Are objects the world generally neutral or slightly charged, constantly passing a little bit of charge from one to the other on contact?

The answer to this is more subtle. At the microlevel of atoms and molecules the electrons exist quantum mechanically in [orbitals](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:D_orbitals.svg) about the nucleus. These orbitals have shapes which allow for localized electric fields that may generate repulsion ( from electrons) or attraction ( from the less shielded protons in the nucleus) dependent on the shape.

[image: atorbit]

> The five d orbitals in ψ(x, y, z)2 form, with a combination diagram showing how they fit together to fill space around an atomic nucleus.

This allows attraction between atoms with the correct orientation in space, and the same happens with molecular orbitals. Like complicated LEGO bricks they "fit" into complex patterns ([latices in solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_structure)), in the process releasing some electromagnetic energy when they settle at the best fit.

Thus even though objects are generally neutral, the charge distributions allow for attractive or repulsive behavior at close contact.